# Add a overlay on AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer programmatically

Tags: ios, uiview, autolayout

I am trying to add a overlay view on top of AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer. Here is my view hierarchy -

```
Preview Container (UIView)
   AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer
       Overlay (UIView)
```

I configured AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer in `viewDidLoad()` and updated its frame in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` as `self.videoPreviewLayer.frame = self.previewContainer.bounds` so that its frame is updated when the preview container's bounds change during render. All is well so far.

**The overlay view is also configured in `viewDidLoad`** as below:

```
    let overlayView = UIView(frame: self.previewContainer.bounds)
        overlayView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.7)
        overlayView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight,.flexibleWidth]
        self.previewContainer.addView(overlayView)
```

However the overlay view doesn't overlay the preview container completely but is actually shorter. After some debugging I found that during creation, since it's frame is set to previewContainer's bounds its height is shorter and doesn't get updated when the previewContainer's frame is redrawn after `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`. I seem to have solved this exact problem for `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` by updating its frame in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` (As shown above). How can I draw the overlayView correctly? What am I doing wrong here?